# old jar files in my android project give error in new project

Tags: android, android-studio, jar

I am using .jar files in my android project.
But when compiling it creates problems.
In Java 1.8 and classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.4' works fine. But this time I cannot use up-to-date technologies (view binding, data binding, ...).

how do i fix this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.